# JQuery ; Declare duplicate global values in

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i have something like these

```
     var executed = false;
    var executed2 = false;
    var executed3 = false;
```

How should i put this in a for loop?

Comment: Depends on what you are suppose to do with those variables..

Comment: nothing much, just 'd like to see if these variable can go into one single on loop for better maintenance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make executed a single array rather than a series of variables.

In that case, you could write:

```
var executed = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  executed.push(false);
}
```

Then, to access the values, you can use:

```
executed[0] === false // ==> true
executed[1] === false // ==> true
executed[2] === false // ==> true
```

Comment: so we use array[] instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array of Objects` instead of using variables in a `loop`

```js
var executed = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  executed.push({
    status: false
  });
}
console.log(executed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global variables, use window[]

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  window['executed' + ( i > 1 ? i : '' )] = false;
}
// now you can access 'executed', 'executed2', 'executed3' globally
```

but, DO NOT use global variables if you can.